# AWS IAM - Access Denied from Lambda to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, url-shortener, iaas

I am following this [tutorial from Medium.com](https://medium.com/@jeeri95/serverless-url-shortener-using-aws-97f1929c475e) to create a URL shortener using AWS.

I have setup the whole thing, but doing my first test I am getting a permissions error when trying to get a DynamoDB item from a Lambda.

As stated in the tutorial, the Lambda runs under a certain rol. That rol has attached the next policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-3:922842442607:table/lambda-dynamodb-url-shortener"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, as I said before, I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetItem operation: User: arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/lambda-dynamodb-url-shortener-role/url-shortener-create is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-3:***:table/url-shortener-table
```

When I check in the IAM Policy Simulator, I can see that the rol has the mentioned policy:

[image]

But, as expected given the error, I am getting this error when trying to simulate the access to DynamoDB with the role:

[image]

Any clue? :(

Comment: The policy resource does not match the actual db: `table/lambda-dynamodb-url-shortener` vs. `table/url-shortener-table`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your policy does not match the actual resource. You reference `table/lambda-dynamodb-url-shortener` in the policy but the error messages mentions `table/url-shortener-table`. Therefore you either need to change the policy to allow access to `table/url-shortener-table` or fix the lambda code to actually talk to a dynamodb table named `lambda-dynamodb-url-shortener`. (Probably the first one fixes the issue)